# com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar Can't get events but "primary"

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

In the MainActivity class I have an AsyncTask inner class to retrieve events from a calendar:

```
private class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<>> {

    private com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar mService;
    private Exception mLastError = null;

    MakeRequestTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {

        HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

        mService = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
                transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            return getDataFromApi();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            mLastError = e;
            cancel(true);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private List<> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {

        DateTime now = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());

        List<> eventDates = new ArrayList<>();

                Events events = mService.events().list("primary")
                .setMaxResults(30)
                .setTimeMin(now)
                .setOrderBy("startTime")
                .setSingleEvents(true)
                .execute();

        List<Event> items = events.getItems();

        String sameDateTime = null;
        boolean showDate;

        for (Event event : items) {

            DateTime start = event.getStart().getDateTime();

            eventDates.add(new AppointmentItem(event.getId(),
                    start,
                    event.getSummary(),
                    event.getLocation())
            );
        }

        return eventDates;
    }
}
```

It works fine if in the list method I pass "primary" as the calendar ID `Events events = mService.events().list("primary")`.

This is the default one, but I want to retrieve the events from every calendars associated to the particular account.

So I seeked around and I found that `CalendarList calendarList = mService.calendarList().list().execute();` can get all the data from calendars (including the calendar's ID), but if I put the ID in the previous statement, I get back no events.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is the authorized user and the `calendar ID` the same? If it is not, then unless the calendar you are calling is public or shared to the authorized user, you will not be able to get any events.

Comment: Hi @Mr.Rebot, I think it's the same because mService is the same instance of com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar. In calendarList I have a different owner account for the shared calendar and no authorized user. How can I check/set the authorized one?

Comment: I got confused, you are accessing the calendar of the user? right?

Comment: Yes, mService (an instance of Calendar) can retrieve the events for the "primary" calendar. My problem is to access some or all of the calendars owned by the same user. I think the difficulty is in the calendar ID, how can I select the shared ones? In my calendar account I have 6 calendars, if I put the ID provided in the calendar's setting I get events only for 1 calendar (and the primary).